# Siebzehn or Siebenzehn?

Tags: numbers

Why Siebzehn and why not Siebenzehn? Any reason or is just kind of a thumb rule? I understand that every language would have such a ruleset. But I'm just trying to confirm it. I'm a self learner so I don't have someone to go and ask in person.

Comment: I have already heard *siebenzehn* e.g. when somebody gives a number via phone, in a possibly over-correcting attempt (apparently assuming to be faster than giving the digits one by one). So it may be in the same category as *zwo* , *fünnef* and *Julai* (instead of Juli, since quite similar to *Juni*).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's quite common for languages to have (slightly) irregular forms for numbers between 10 and 20, and multiples of 10. Sometimes letters are dropped because you don't hear them, sometimes there's a vowel change, sometimes something else is going on. Consider

- English:

  - 13 = *thir*teen, not *three*teen; 30 = *thir*ty, not *three*ty
  - 40 = *for*ty, not *four*ty
  - 15 = *fif*teen, not *five*teen; 50 = *fif*ty, not *five*ty
  - 18 = *eigh*teen, not *eight*teen; 80 = *eigh*ty, not *eight*ty
- Dutch:

  - 13 = *der*tien, not *drie*tien; 30 = *der*tig, not *drie*tig
  - 14 = *veer*tien, not *vier*tien; 40 = *veer*tig, not *vier*tig
  - 80 = *tach*tig, not *acht*tig
- Russian:

  - 14 = *четыр*надцать, not *четырe*надцать (I'm not even talking about 40)

So yes, *sieb*zehn is irregular, as is 16 (it's *sech*zehn, not *sechs*zehn). Some multiples of 10 are also slightly irregular:

- 20 = *zwan*zig, not *zwei*zig
- 30 = drei*ß*ig, not drei*z*ig
- 60 = *sech*zig, not *sechs*zig
- 70 = *sieb*zig, not *sieben*zig

Answer (score 0):

Siebzehn - not *Siebenzehn*

There’s no rules, just habits, in all languages.

People are lazy, that’s all.

Why “Moin” and not “Morgen”? Why “Morgen” and not “guten Morgen”? and so on ...

Comment: "Moin" has nothing to do with "Morgen".

Comment: and *Tschüss* nothing with á Dieux? and Dieux nothing with Zeus?  https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/84628/scale-in-thirds-vs-scales-a-third-apart-what-is-the-difference

Comment: »Moin« ist ein Dialektwort, das nicht im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum verbreitet ist. In Österreich beispielsweise ist »moin« nicht gebräuchlich. Wir Ösis sagen »moagn« [moɐ̯ŋ]. Außerdem wird »moin« in einem Schulaufsatz als Fehler markiert, das Wort steht in keinem amtlichen Bescheid und wird, außer in wörtlichen Zitaten, nich in Zeitungen und Büchern gedruckt. Das alles trifft auf »siebzehn« nicht zu. »Siebzehn« steht im Duden, in Gesetzen, Zeitungen und Büchern, ist im ganzen dt. Sprachraum in Verwendung und gilt in Schulaufsätzen als korrekt.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: wiewohl "Moin" ein Dialektwort ist, habe ich ohne eigenen Beweis trotzdem Zweifel, dass es in keiner norddeutschen (lokalen) Zeitung gedruckt wird. Bedingt durch die Eigenschaft "Grusswort" natürlich wenn dann in Interviews so wie auch in (den hier ausgesparten) Audio-Medien.

Comment: Für die Hügelbewohner: *Moin* heißt *Gudn*, nicht *Morgen*. Deshalb kann man das auch den ganzen *Tach* über sagen.

Comment: Und gudn heisst guten Morgen. Das ganze hier beweist nur meine Feststellung, dass es sich um Abkürzungen und Sprechfaulheit handelt und meine allg. Beobachtung, dass die Leute nicht mehr wissen, was sie sagen. Siebenzehn wäre ja viel zu langweilig ... ursprünglich hiess es wohl: Sieben und Zehn.

Comment: @Loong Also zumindest laut [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moin#Herkunft) ist das nicht so völlig unumstritten.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm: Genau das habe ich mit *»außer in wörtlichen Zitaten«* gemeint.

Comment: @Albrecht Hügli - *"... dass die Leute nicht mehr wissen, was sie sagen."* Sieh an! Weißt **du** denn, was du mit **be-** sagst, wenn du *berühren* sagst, oder *begleiten*? Oder mit **ver-**, wenn du *vergessen* sagst? Jetzt sag mal besser nicht Ja, sonst passiert das: :-)) - Im übrigen heißt das, was du als "Sprachfaulheit" anprangerst, *Sprachpragmatik*. ;-)

Comment: @ multiplex et liber: Ja, leider ist es so, dass ich mir schon seit über 50 Jahren darüber Sorgen mache, wie unsere Sprache verkommt und verkümmert. Der etymologische Duden und das Wörterbuch “Sex im Volksmund” von Dornemann stehen sowohl auf meinem Nachttischlein wie Freuds “Psychopathologie des Alltagslebens”, die Bibel und die Konkordanz ... Es ist wie eine Sucht - von Klein auf - bei jedem Wort zu fragen: Woher kommt es? Was ist damit gemeint? Und was war seine ursprüngliche Bedeutung?

Comment: Darum, eigentlich müsste die Frage lauten: Warum heisst es eigentlich sieb-en und sev-en und nicht sieb und sevn?